# install ipython notebook on my mac OS X 10.7.5

Tags: macos, installation, ipython

I recently updated my Python from 2.7 to 3.4.
I am trying to install  ipython notebook on my mac OS X 10.7.5.

```
$ easy_install ipython3.4
python: posix_spawn: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/
Resources/Python.app/Cont    ents/MacOS/Python: No such file or directory
```

Also I have

```
$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3
```

and

```
$which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Could anybody help me figure it out? What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
pip install "ipython[notebook]"
```

there are some issues with easy_install and mac.

so i gave this a try on my mac book pro and ran into the same error, although i have both python version installed just fine. and "oh my god" how could i forget to mention... ha, ha, and i ran into the same trap :D

ofcourse **THIS** is the correct way of installing and most likely you did not have to reinstall your python:

```
sudo -H pip install "ipython[notebook]"
```

you need **sudo** because you are installing in system directories and **-H** to set the HOME environment var to homedir of target user. using this installation works like a charm.

Comment: I get the same error with pip. I guess I have deleted Python 2.7 inadvertently! Isn't it? Is there a way I fix this issue?

Comment: @Elham i ran into the same issue, because i also forgot to prefix command with **sudo** :) see my comment in answer